# MySQL: troubles with HAVING COUNT 'exact', not 'at least'

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds relations of users participating in conversations like follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `so` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `conversation_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `so`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `uc` (`user_id`,`conversation_id`) USING BTREE;

INSERT INTO `so` (`id`, `user_id`, `conversation_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 2),
(2, 2, 1),
(4, 2, 2),
(5, 3, 2);
```

According to sample data, users 1 and 2 have conversation with ID of 1 and users 1, 2, 3 - conversation with ID of 2.

I need to get unique `conversation_id` for the list of user ids.

My current query is:

```
SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(user_id) as usersCount
FROM so
WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING usersCount = 2
ORDER BY NULL
```

But it returns 2 rows for both conversations and I expect the row with  conversation_id of 1.

How can I select the row that belongs exactly to users 1 and 2, and not to 1, 2, 3? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
I can't use subqueries on joins for performance reasons because users list in the query may be up to 30 ids and I'm afraid 30 subqueries is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group_concat`

```
select conversation_id
from so
group by conversation_id
having group_concat(user_id order by user_id) = '1,2';
```

To avoid full index scan, you can put your original query in a subquery:

```
SELECT a.conversation_id
FROM (
    SELECT conversation_id
    FROM so
    WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY conversation_id
    HAVING COUNT(conversation_id) = 2) a
JOIN so b ON a.conversation_id = b.conversation_id
GROUP BY a.conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(a.conversation_id) = 2;
```

Comment: thanks, this query works. Is there a way to avoid full index scan, as the table will be relatively big.

Comment: Can you explain what group_concat actually does? I see it gets the right result set. I often use the queries like the one in my answer for similar situations and could possible benefit from understanding this.

Comment: @Kanstantsin, see updated answer. @AdamCopley, `group_concat` behaves like `implode(',', $items)` in php

Comment: @Fabricator, unfortunately, I'm getting "Invalid use of group function" with the second query.

Comment: @Kanstantsin, sorry I didn't test it. it should work now

Comment: @Fabricator, yep, now it works, thanks! It seems slower than the first one for me still uses index scan on a subquery. Could you suggest proper indexes, please?

Comment: @Kanstantsin, the subquery uses `user_id`, which is already indexed. the next query uses `conversation_id`. so you may try to add an index to `conversation_id`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking the `user_id` in the `WHERE` clause, compare the number of rows that satisfy that condition with the total rows for each conversation.

```
SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(*) AS allCount, SUM(user_id IN (1, 2)) AS userCount
FROM so
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING allCount = 2 AND allCount = userCount
```

Comment: After filling a table with the large amount of data, seems like your query the only that did the job. How do you think, is there any way to avoid full index scan and improve performance of the query?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an alternative to the already given, and will provide better efficiency through not using sub-selects.

`HAVING COUNT(user_id IN ('1','2') OR NULL) > 0` specifies that you want conversations with userid 1 and 2.

`COUNT(user_id) = 2` says that there can only be 2 users in the conversation.

You could even remove `COUNT(user_id) as usersCount` from the result set if you don't actually use it as part of your exercise.

```
SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(user_id) as usersCount
FROM so
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id IN ('1','2') OR NULL) > 0 AND
COUNT(user_id) = 2;
```

To avoid a full index scan you would have to use a `where` clause as @Fabricator has shown in his answer. When you apply conditions to groups of rows, it has to group them first, and then do the aggregations and conditions, and a `where` clause only applies conditions to **single rows**. How big is your table out of interest?

Comment: This one works too, thanks. Could you advice how to avoid full index scan, please?

Comment: Potentially table may have several millions of rows.

Comment: Are these the only columns in the table which are used and filtered or is this trimmed down just for ease of explanation? If it's just the 3, then simply an `INDEX` on `(user_id, conversation_id)` would give you the best results.

Comment: I have a similar situation where I filter product data in a similar manner with up to 3M rows, which I am struggling to optimize, however there are a few joins too which don't help the situation. On a single table with no joins, a query like any 3 answered here will do the trick.